# Easy and safe way to open and close system port by python

Tags: python, iptables

**My purpose is simple**: Setup a restful service on a vps for `open and close system port` on this machine.

**More detail**:
I want to use a lot vps as proxy for my customer, it need control when the customer can access a vps.If a customer buy a one month plan, I choose a vps port(with password) allow him in, and ban him when expired.I can not just change the password, because it does not protect from brute force attack.

This is a very simple requirement, but I don't find a a convenient way to achieve this.

The approach I found:

1. `iptables`, need to learn bash shell and iptables , and use python construct a proper command, then use `os.system('some cmd')` to run.
2. [python-iptables](https://github.com/ldx/python-iptables): It still need the knowledge of `iptables`, or you can not figure how it works.

`iptables` could do such job, but is really not convenient to use in a restful service.And it may break the whole network if rule order goes wrong, very danger for newbie.

Is there a way or higher level packages could do such work conveniently and safely?

Comment: Usually you would open and close a TCP or UDP port by starting and stopping the responsible daemon. But this actually question better suited for Server Fault.

Comment: You don't want to reset a password, but you want a web service to be able to run root privileged firewall commands? Stop brute force attacks with delays after a few queries and temporary account lockouts.